# Filtering Graphite metrics by server

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd

I've recently done a lot of research into graphite with statsD instrumentation. With help of our developer operations team we managed to get multiple servers reporting metrics to graphite, and combine all the metrics. This is partially what we are looking for, however I want to filter the metric collection by server rather than having all the metrics be averaged together. The purpose of this is to monitor metrics collection on a per server basis, as many of our stats could also be used to visualize server uptime and performance. I haven't been able to find anything about how this may be achieved in my research, other than maybe some trickery with the aggregation rules.

Comment: If you go to the main url of your graphite server, you can drill down into your metrics.  graphite >> servers >> <server> >> <metric> and get some nice per-host graphs.  If you like the graphs, you can save them or add them to your own dashboards.  Do you need something different than that?

Answer (score 3):

You should include the server name as the first path component of the metric name being emitted. When naming metrics, Graphite separates the metric name into path components using `.` as the delimiter between path components. For example, you may want to use a naming schema like: `<data_center>_<environment>_<role>_<node_id>.gauges.cpu.idle_pct` This will cause each server to be listed as a separate category on http://graphite_hostname.com/dashboard/

If you need to perform aggregations across servers, you can do that at the graphite layer, or you could emit the same metric under two different names: one metric name that has the first path component as the server name, and one metric name that has the first path component as a value that is shared across all servers you want that metric aggregated across.